# Question about asympotic behavior of $\frac{1}{s}\int_0^s u(x,t) dt$ .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

I am just reading a paper, in the final theorem, the author wants to prove that $u(x,t)$ converges to some $v(x)$ in the $L^2$ norm as $t$ $\to$ $\infty$. But in the proof, he defines a $w(x,s)=\frac{1}{s}\int_0^s u(x,t) dt$, and he only proves that as $s$ tends to $\infty$, $w(x,s)$ converges to $v(x)$ in the $L^2$ norm. So my question is: Does $w(x,s)$ represent $u(x,t)$ as $s$ $\to$ $\infty$($t$ $\to$ $\infty$)?
Thanks!

Comment: Should we use the mean value theorem? But it will not yield the desired result.

Comment: @Winther. Sorry, what the author wants to prove is that $\lim_{t\to\infty} u(x,t) = v(x)$.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you want a result like "if $w(x,s) \to v(x)$ then $u(x,t)\to v(x)$.". Consider following my first advice: add the source to the problem.

Comment: [Chen, Yunmei(1-FL); Rao, Murali(1-FL)
Minimization problems and associated flows related to weighted p energy and total variation. (English summary) 
SIAM J. Math. Anal. 34 (2003), no. 5, 1084–1104. 
49J40 (35J20)](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036141002404577),at the bottom of page 1099.

Comment: @Winther. Yes, this is what I want.

Comment: [Variable exponent, linear growth functionals in image restoration.SIAM J. Appl. Math. 66 (2006), no. 4, 1383–1406 (electronic)](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/050624522), page 1396.